# Xcode's Build setting for minumum run on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I have finally reached to the point where i need to set the build settings for my iphone application.I want to my App to run on 4.3 to 6.0.1 and devices from iPhone 3gs to 5.

Are the following build setting for the target valid and correct? Notice i have changed the armv7 to armv6.Should i change it again or is it safe to leave it like this?

Also should i add armv6 to Valid Architercures(appstore scheme)?

[image: settings]

[image: settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Valid Architecture for armv7 and armv7s as for iPhone 3GS and further devices has support for armv7. iPhone 3G is having armv6, so no use of it as you are not supporting iPhone 3G.

Also, your iOS target set to iOS 4.3 is proper.

Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score 1):

the 3gs can run armv7 just fine so why do you need it?

Comment: aha,so armv7 only should do the job.